# CSS Scroll Snapping, vertical not working

Tags: css

I used [this article](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/) as a point of reference, in particular [this working snippet](https://codepen.io/maxakohler/pen/KBKNxd), but in my page (the script below) the vertical snap scrolling isn't working. Why?

```css
.parent {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  position: relative;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
}

.three {
  background-color: grey;
}

.four {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent row">
  <section class="one">
  </section>
  <section class="two">
  </section>
  <section class="three">
  </section>
  <section class="four">
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I fix immediately...sorry

Comment: I'm curious to see what you get for answers.  I'm unfamiliar with `scroll-snap`, and I'm seeing mixed / interesting things out there....

Comment: I am also curious how this works. In 2022 scroll snapping seems to work well in Firefox but is broken in Chrome, see my comments to below answers.

Comment: (Why is the syntax highlighting inconsistent between, for example, `scroll-snap-align` and `background-color`?)

Comment: @PeterMortensen there is no such thing as `scroll-snap-points` is there?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The major problem in the code snippet is that the displayed scrollbar belongs to the body, where no scroll-snap properties have been defined. This is why you do not have any snapping behaviour when scrolling.

To achieve your expected result, you need to

1. Be sure that the displayed scrollbar belongs to the parent *div*
2. Define the `overflow` behaviour to the parent container to `scroll`

Below is a working sample

As a note, consider that snapping properties (for Chrome) have evolved, and that you are using deprecated features. See the [CSS scroll snap on Google developers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/css-scroll-snap).

Note also that this answer deals only with Chrome, without the [polyfill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill_(programming)) part. It is just the main scroll concept that is involved here.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.parent {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
  position: relative;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
}

.three {
  background-color: grey;
}

.four {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent row">
  <section class="one"></section>
  <section class="two"></section>
  <section class="three"></section>
  <section class="four"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation Piiantom!!

Comment: This works well in Firefox, but in Chrome there is a delay between the scroll steps.

Comment: `scroll-snap-points-y` has been deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-points-y

Comment: Thanks bro. nice explanation with a good example.

Answer (score 17):

[The original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416348/css-scroll-snapping-vertical-not-working/53417516#53417516) says to put `overflow: hidden` directly on the `html` and `body` elements which messes up a lot of things, namely headers that use `position: sticky` which is a pretty common concept.

The alternative is to just put the `scroll-snap-type` property on the body and then put the `scroll-snap-align` property on the elements that need to have scroll snap behavior.

```css
body, html {
  scroll-snap-type: proximity;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
  scroll-snap-type: y proximity;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

.row section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.one {
  background-color: red;
}

.two {
  background-color: blue;
}

.three {
  background-color: grey;
}

.four {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <section class="one">
  </section>
  <section class="two">
  </section>
  <section class="three">
  </section>
  <section class="four">
  </section>
</div>
<section>
  <h2>This will not have sticky</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: This is so much better. Now I can use the native scroll bar and not some inset garbage created by a div. Thanks

Comment: This also works well in Firefox but doesn't snap at all in Chrome

Comment: @NilsLindemann I only use Chrome - so not sure why its not working for you. Works great for me.

Comment: @MikeHarrison I am on a Windows 7 without graphics card. I guess that is the reason. The examples on this page are not the only ones which do not work when scrolling with the mouse wheel. E.g. none of the examples [here](https://css-tricks.com/practical-css-scroll-snapping/) work properly. The horizontal scroll examples do nothing at all, the other examples snap, but with a delay. First it scrolls, then there is a short delay of approximately 0.5 seconds, then it snaps. I can get the delayed snapping with your example, when I replace `proximity` with `mandatory`.

Comment: @NilsLindemann Oh Windows 7...are you on an old Chrome version? Sticky scrolling is a new-ish feature https://caniuse.com/?search=scroll%20snap

Comment: @MikeHarrison I am on the latest Chrome. I pasted an answer below, trying to emulate the correct behavior using JavaScript, but I more or less failed.

Comment: Great solution! I don't think the solution works, however, when replacing `y proximity` with `y mandatory` (not at least for Safari 15.2, Chrome 104, or Opera 89; it seems to work for Firefox 102 partially - you can scroll snap within the scroll container and scroll normally downwards outside of the scroll container, but scrolling upwards outside of the scroll container instantly snaps to the last item within the scroll container).

Comment: @StackOverflow and this is when you run the snippet above? It just worked for me (not snapping to the last item in the list when I scroll upwards) I was able to scroll through each element both directions just fine. I'm on Chrome 104.

Answer (score 2):

The following is my current best attempt to work around the Chrome bug mentioned in the previous comments, using JavaScript. **Run it full screen**. I guess scrolling in browsers will never be as smooth as in file managers. That's life.

**Warning** I should add that many people will not like if a website changes in the middle how scrolling behaves. It may be a good idea to leave regions on the left and right where scrolling behaves normal. Please consider the below code example for what it is, an attempt to work around a bug in Chromes implementation of the CSS-only feature. (See my comments to the other answers)

```js
let adjusted = false

function snapscroll(event) {
    let snappable = null; {
        let hovered = document.elementsFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY)
        for (elem of hovered) {
            if (elem.classList.contains('snapme')) {
                snappable = elem
                break
            }
        }
    }

    let prev = null
    let next = null
    if (snappable !== null) {
        prev = snappable.previousElementSibling; if (prev !== null && !prev.classList.contains('snapme')) {prev = null}
        next = snappable.nextElementSibling; if (next !== null && !next.classList.contains('snapme')) {next = null}
    }

    if (event.deltaY > 0) {
        if (next === null) {
            snappable = null
            adjusted = false
        } else {
            if (adjusted) {
                snappable = next
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (prev === null) {
            snappable = null
            adjusted = false
        } else {
            if (adjusted) {
                snappable = prev
            }
        }
    }


    if (snappable !== null) {
        snappable.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"})
        adjusted = true
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
    }
}

let doit
document.addEventListener('wheel', function(event) {
    clearTimeout(doit)
    doit = setTimeout(() => snapscroll(event), 25)
})
```

```css
body {padding:1em;}
section { height: 100vh; }
.snapme {cursor:move;}
.one { background-color: red; }
.two { background-color: blue; }
.three { background-color: grey; }
.four { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<section>
    <h2>No snapping here</h2>
</section>

<section class='snapme one'></section>
<section class='snapme two'></section>
<section class='snapme three'></section>
<section class='snapme four'></section>

<section>
    <h2>No snapping here</h2>
</section>
```

Comment: The OP did ask for CSS only scroll snapping, not javascript

Comment: @MikeHarrison _read_ my answer and my comments.

Comment: I did...but you didn't actually provide an answer the OP was asking for...

Comment: You provided a workaround that uses Javascript - there's many reasons why a Javascript is not desirable which is why the OP asked for CSS only solutions. The main reason being performance.

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, the problem was that i had overflow: hidden, on the extra wrapper in html - site, i ended up in having something like this:

```
<html>
    <div class="site">
          <div class="video"></div>
          <div class="fixed-height"></div>
    </div>
</html>
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory ;
}
.site {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.fixed-height,
.video {
  scroll-snap-align: start ;
}
```