# scroll-snap-align and scroll-snap-type not enough?

Tags: css

I'm trying to use this :
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-align

Example I want to reproduce: https://codepen.io/mykiwi/pen/xxwPKJr?editors=1100

```html
<div class="scroller">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
</div>
```

```css
.scroller {
  text-align:left;
  height:250px;
  width:270px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:1px solid #000;
  scroll-snap-type:y mandatory
}
.scroller>div {
  flex:0 0 250px;
  background-color:#663399;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:30px;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  scroll-snap-align:start;
}
.scroller>div:nth-child(even) {
  background-color:#fff;
  color:#663399
}
```

My code: https://codepen.io/mykiwi/pen/mdeqePo?editors=1100
I have [Bulma](https://bulma.io/) in background too

What is wrong/missing from my CSS to reproduce the example ?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit tricky to get it working and since the MDN does not describe it very well, this makes it harder.

---

### What is the problem exactly?

The wrapping element you provided does not meet the expectation for doing such an action. So what does it mean?

To ensure the `scroll-snap-type` is working correctly **we should make sure the only available scrollbar in our window is our wrapping element scrollbar**, which is in your case it is a division by class name `screen`.

### How to fix it?

So all you have to do is to **make sure the scroll element is exactly related to your parent wrapping element** which in your case its indicated by `screen` class name. To make sure the scrollbar you seeing in the right one **you should make the `body` and `html`, overflow to `hidden` to prevent them from scrolling.** just like this:

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Then you need to enable the right scrollbar**, which belongs to the `screen` division.

```css
.screen {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
```

So it will work like a charm.

Here is the live working example: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/smalikss/pen/ZEbabdx?editors=0100)

---

Also, there is a similar issue in SO, that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53416348/11908502).

Comment: How would you go about removing the CSS scroll snap on a mobile breakpoint, for example, less max-width 375px? @SMAKSS

Comment: @timSully You can simply create a media and set the `scroll-snap-type` to `none` or `unset` it.