# CSS Scroll Snap Behaviour like Firefox

Tags: css, scroll-snap-points, scroll-snap, scroll-snap-type

I've encountered a problem on every browser other than firefox on macos and android (havent tested windows and ios) where the scroll snapping is delayed. On Firefox it works beautifully, but on Edge, Chrome and Safari it's delayed. Is there any fix for this?

My code:

```css
.scroll-snap-container {
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(100vh);
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    overflow-scrolling: touch; /* Needed to work on iOS Safari */
    overflow: auto;
}
.scroll-snap-container > div {
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
    position: relative;
}
p {
  background-color: #000a;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
img {
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-snap-container">
    <div>
        <p>Long text here.</p>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any/sepia"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Long text here.</p>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/641/480/any/sepia"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Long text here.</p>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/642/480/any/sepia"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Added html snippet

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416348/css-scroll-snapping-vertical-not-working

Comment: html code please

Comment: @barhatsor No, scroll snapping works for me, it is just delayed on Chrome, safari and edge. When i scroll there's around a second before it snaps, whereas on Firefox it does it instantly.

Comment: Here's a codepen:
https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/qpJYaK

Works smoothly on Firefox but not on other browsers.
I think a few months ago it did work fine :/

Comment: It's now a known issue in the chromium bug tracker:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1220732&q=scroll%20snap%20delay&can=2