# How should create a page by page scrolling in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, pagination

i want to create a page that on every scroll page scrolled 100vh

using scrollTo and scrollBy has not good results.

i calculate the vertical height of the screen by this:

```
const [vh,setVh ]=useState(Math.round(window.innerHeight / (100/100)))
```

and use scroll addEventListener to make a scroll on the page and update amount of vh.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll",()=>{
 window.scrollTo(vh,vh) ;
setVh(vh+vh) 
})
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the scrollend event ? addEventListener("scrollend", (event) => {});

Comment: A simple CSS [scroll-snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type) might also do the trick

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=page+by+page+scrolling+react+site:stackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: I think `react` is a more important tag than HTML or element

Comment: @Veterini ,using scrollend event was good effort but ,but it make a repeatable scroll and make scroll automatic until last page.

Comment: @Reyno , it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What doesn't work? Update your question with the attempt, we can't debug code that isn't shown. A working example can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53416348/css-scroll-snapping-vertical-not-working

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with pure css and [scroll-snap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type) (as mentioned in a comment above by [Reyno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3257622/reyno)):

```css
.container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

.container>div {
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>1st</div>
  <div>2nd</div>
  <div>3rd</div>
  <div>4th</div>
  <div>5th</div>
</div>
```

Add the container as a child to the body element and remove the margins of the body to make it full screen.

```css
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```